# Find the address that a global defined pointer is pointing to which used heap allocation

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I'm doing a bit of reverse engineering, I have a program and on it there is a class pointer globally defined.

```
#include <includesandsuch.h>

myclass* g_Class = NULL;

int WinMain( ... )
{
  g_Class = new myclass(0);
}
```

On my class there is a method I want to call from a dll, I tried a function prototype using `__thiscall`which works but the class `this` will be 0 thus crashing the program since the method writes to class members data. Now, I came up with a solution that does work, consider this a SSCE or in this case SLCE.

```
DWORD* g_Input = 0;
void* operator new(size_t sz)
{
    cout << "mynew" << endl; //yes i'm using (using namespace std;) but please focus on the issue
    g_Input = (DWORD*)::new char [sz];
    return g_Input;
}
void *operator new [](size_t size)
{
    // if (size > MAX_SIZE) ...
    cout << "mynew" << endl;
    return malloc(size);
}
class ZInput
{
public:
    ZInput( int n );
    ~ZInput(){};
    void CallMe( int n, DWORD b );
private:
    int m_nData;
};
ZInput::ZInput( int n ){
    m_nData = n;
}
void ZInput::CallMe( int n, DWORD b ) { 
    cout << n <<" "<< b << endl;
}
void Fake_RealSpace2_Input( int n, DWORD b )
{
    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, g_Input
        mov eax, 0x012C7310 //example address of ZInput::CallMe
        push n
        push b
        call eax
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ZInput* pInput = new ZInput(2);
    cout << pInput << endl;
    cout << g_Input << endl;

    Fake_RealSpace2_Input(4,5 );

    delete pInput;

    return 0;
}
```

this way I can successfully make a call to `ZInput::CallMe` on a valid `ZInput` class object.

Now my problem is that I want to port this code to a DLL, and call `ZInput::CallMe` from there (the class ZInput is on the main application and I want to call it from a dll), as I have the address of `CallMe` I'll only need the address of `g_Class` (`g_Class` is on the main application, and on the main application `WinMain` g_Class pointer will point to a `new` heap allocated object), the problem is that I cannot overload operator new from a dll for obvious reasons. Supposing that on the main application `g_Class` is the only data-type that uses `new` how can I find the address that `g_Class` points to from my dll?

Comment: Can you hook the constructor so it may return the pointer when called?

Comment: Oh I can hook constructors? Wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive way to find a pointer in a target application. It take some practise and experience.

A good start for your case would be to break at the start of the original CallMe function with a debugger and read ECX to get the original class pointer. Now you could set a memory breakpoint on it (or use cheat engine's "find out what accesses this address") and work from there to eventually end up in a static address from which you can always get the dynamic address of the class instance.

---

If the class uses a virtual table because of polymorphism, you can locate the function pointer (ZInput::CallMe) in there. This is an example of a virtual function call you could find in your target application:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump              Command      
006A4F94    8B4E 38             MOV ECX,(class ptr)
006A4F97    8B01                MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
006A4F99    8B50 04             MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
006A4F9C    FFD2                CALL EDX
```

The class ptr is loaded to ECX for thiscall. The virtual table ptr is read out (the VT is located as the first member). The member function ptr is read from the table and is called (here the second entry in the table).

For this example the definition of ZInput would look like this:

```
class ZInput
{
public:
    virtual void unknown();
    virtual void CallMe(int, DWORD);
};
```

Now to call the member function you can directly call it on a valid class (not your own allocated!):

```
ZInput *inp = *(ZInput**)(0x01112233 + 0x8); // example to get pointer
inp->CallMe(4, 5);
```

If it doesnt use a virtual function table, you have use a static value for the function pointer and some assembly hacking to call like you did. But ECX still has to be the class instance of the target and not your own.